# Drupal 7: using CCK field in html.tpl.php for custom page title for each entry

Tags: drupal, cck, drupal-7, meta, drupal-theming

I need to give a custom meta title to each page. I found a module http://drupal.org/project/page_title but I cant give particular title to entry with that.

I created MetaTitle field for my CCK. then I edited html.tpl.php as below, and it doesn't take action. do I call my cck field wrong way? :/

**/sites/all/themes/zen/html.tpl.php**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>"<?php print $rdf_namespaces; ?>>

<head profile="<?php print $grddl_profile; ?>">
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <title><?php print $node->field_meta_title[0]['view']; ?></title>
  <?php //print $head_title; I removed the line ?>
```

What am I missing? Appreciate helps!!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you an exact answer, but I'm pretty sure you don't want to be editing anything in the `modules` folder to do this.

You'll probably find that the place to do this is in your theme.  The exact location varies by theme, but you should be able to find it with a minimal amount of hunting.

Comment: i passed that part, i suppoed to edit the html.tpl.pgp in ZEN folder. now it takes action when I edit, but i cant call my cck field into html.tpl.php now :/  <?php print $node->field_meta_title[0]['view']; ?> doesnt work